# Way to enforce length check constraint in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have some check constraints defined by SYS schema in DB for a particular column.
Now, while invoking it from Java code through MyBatis, is there anyway to enforce corresponding field length validations through MYBatis configuration only.

*PS: I don't want to enforce constraints at VO level (setter individually). Or using JSR 303*

DataBase : Oracle 11g
Using MyBatis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to validate in your java beans (manually, or using JSR 303) I think you could write your own typeHandler for those field.

Typehandler would handle String fields and do validation.
See [code example for String TypeHandler](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers). 
You could enforce your validation logic (of any complexity) in handler's get/set methods.

If you want to use TypeHandler to trim string to given length when saving to database, do it in *setNonNullParameter* method.

Sample code below

```
    @MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.VARCHAR)
   public class ExampleTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<String> {
    @Override
      public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, 
String parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        ps.setString(i, parameter.substring(0,DESIRED_MAX_LENGTH));
      }
```

You could also trim (or otherwise modify) values you read from database- you need to modify get* method in your TypeHandler implementation to do that.

You must tell mappers to use your handler. Otherwise, default handler for given type will be used. 
Your SQLs in XML file must use syntax

```
#{age,javaType=int,jdbcType=NUMERIC,typeHandler=MyTypeHandler}
```

Check https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html for details.

Comment: Thank you for reply. However my scenario is like whenever a column value gets exceeded from a particular length, I just need to chop (substr it).  Do we have a way to do the same.

Comment: could you add more details? Does it not compile, throws exception, does nothig? I think it would be best to edit my answer and provide details there.
I fixed bug in my answer- it trims string before it is passed to DB. You could check strinng length and fail with exception if  you prefer instead.

Comment: I guess we had made some modifications in above definition. Earlier it was not compiling. Above solution is working for all instances where we are using Prepared statement. But if I want to use it in Mapper.xml files, then how to do it. (PS: Some of my queries are in .xml files).